# JS while loop array[i++]. How does it work?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, merge

I'm wondering how it works. I guess that "right[r++]" increments "r" in while loop. Or it shows which element of "right" we push to "result"?

```
function merge(left, right){
  var result = [],
      lLen = left.length,
      rLen = right.length,
      l = 0,
      r = 0;
  while(l < lLen && r < rLen){
     if(left[l] < right[r]){
       result.push(left[l++]);
     }
     else{
       result.push(right[r++]);
    }
  }  
  return result.concat(left.slice(l)).concat(right.slice(r));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: the question is, what does not work, what is your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
result.push(right[r++]);
```

is essentially shorthand for

```
result.push(right[r]);
r = r + 1;
```

The ++ operator after the variable returns the variable's value before it gets incremented.

For comparison, using it before the variable

```
result.push(right[++r]);
```

would achieve the same result as

```
r = r + 1;
result.push(right[r]);
```

Comment: ++r will increment before return ;)

Answer (score 1):

right[r++] is same like writing this:

```
right[r]
r=r+1
```

This was called post-increment. There is also pre-increment. It would be written like this:

```
right[++r]
```

It would be eqvivalent to

```
r=r+1
right[r]
```